# htaccess to rename url : subdomain pointing a php file within it

Tags: .htaccess, url, directory, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to rewrite a url which is in my subdomain directory for my new project. I want

> `http://sub.domain.com/download.php?id=56&name=Mango`
>
> **looks like >>**
>
> `http://sub.domain.com/game/56/Mango`

Is it possible with .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file in `sub.domain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^game/(\d+)/([^/]+)/?$ download.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Yes sure just change first condition to `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]` (remove `sub`)

Comment: `RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^game/([0-9]+)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ download.php?id=$1&name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`

see directory is `/public_html/sub` and download.php file is located as `/public_html/sub/download.php`

Comment: And what URL are you using for this download page. Is it `http://sub.domain.com/game/56/Mango` OR something else?

Comment: http://sub.domain.com/download.php?id=56&name=Mango

looks like >>

http://sub.domain.com/game/56/Mango

Comment: So what error are you getting when you open this URL: `http://sub.domain.com/game/56/Mango` in your browser?

Comment: Also make sure you use the rule as I wrote and make sure it is first rule without changing anything.